# text area box which suggests suggestions as well as text in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I need to create a box which will have text as well as suggestions

```
for eg : hi @<Suggestions>user 
It must look like : hi @Chris
```

I can use gwt suggestion box too by adding condition that when '@' is typed, show suggestion. But when I choose the suggestion, it clears the text box and adds selected suggestion in it, where I need the entered text too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you will find a complete working example (built and tested with GWT 2.7.0).

The [`SuggestBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) consists of

- [`SuggestOracle`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestOracle.html) ([`MultiWordSuggestOracle`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.html) specifically)
- [`ValueBoxBase`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueBoxBase.html) ([`TextArea`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextArea.html) or [`TextBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBox.html))
- and [`SuggestionDisplay`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay.html) ([`DefaultSuggestionDisplay`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay.html))

We need to override some methods in all those parts to get what you want.

The idea is to let the `ValueBox` work as usual by blocking the suggest list. We unblock the list only after `@` is pressed. We also need to alter the query, so it does not contain the text entered before `@` was pressed. Finally, after the selection is done, we need to restore the previously entered text and combine it with the text just selected.

You will find mode information in the code. I hope it is quite self-explanatory. I left the `import` part for clarity.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.MultiWordSuggestOracle;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestBox.SuggestionCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SuggestOracle.Suggestion;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBoxBase;

public class PartialSuggestBox extends Composite {

    private static final char SUGGESTION_TRIGGER_CHAR = '@';

    private String startingText;
    private String endingText;
    private boolean showSuggestions;

    private MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle;
    private TextBoxBase box;
    private SuggestBox suggestBox;

    public PartialSuggestBox() {

        ArrayList<String> suggestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        suggestionList.add("Adam");
        suggestionList.add("Chris");
        suggestionList.add("John");
        suggestionList.add("Joe");
        suggestionList.add("Jane");
        suggestionList.add("Bob");

        oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle() {
            @Override
            public void requestSuggestions(Request request, Callback callback) {
                if(showSuggestions) {
                    // the original query contains all text from the TextBox
                    // so we need to remove the unnecessary parts
                    // leave just the part entered after showing suggestions
                    String query = request.getQuery();
                    query = query.substring(startingText.length(), query.length() - endingText.length());

                    // there are two different methods for empty and non-empty query
                    if(query.isEmpty()) {
                        request.setQuery(null);
                        super.requestDefaultSuggestions(request, callback);
                    }
                    else {
                        request.setQuery(query);
                        super.requestSuggestions(request, callback);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // set suggestion list for empty query
        oracle.setDefaultSuggestionsFromText(suggestionList);
        // set suggestion list for non-empty query
        oracle.addAll(suggestionList);

        DefaultSuggestionDisplay display = new DefaultSuggestionDisplay() {
            @Override
            protected void showSuggestions(SuggestBox suggestBox, Collection<? extends Suggestion> suggestions, boolean isDisplayStringHTML, boolean isAutoSelectEnabled, SuggestionCallback callback) {
                // override showSuggestions to be able to suppress it 
                if(showSuggestions)
                    super.showSuggestions(suggestBox, suggestions, isDisplayStringHTML, isAutoSelectEnabled, callback);
            }

            @Override
            public void hideSuggestions() {
                // when suggestions are hidden we again start to suppress them
                super.hideSuggestions();
                showSuggestions = false;
            }
        };

        box = new TextArea();
        // box = new TextBox(); // you can use TextArea or TextBox
        box.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                if(event.getCharCode() == SUGGESTION_TRIGGER_CHAR) {
                    // run deferred to let the TextBox consume the new char
                    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute() {
                            // get the text parts existing in the TextBox
                            // we will need to remove them for new suggestions
                            int cursorPosition = box.getCursorPos();
                            startingText = box.getText().substring(0, cursorPosition);
                            endingText = box.getText().substring(cursorPosition);

                            // now we stop to suppress showing suggestions
                            showSuggestions = true;
                            suggestBox.showSuggestionList();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // put it all together
        suggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle, box, display);
        suggestBox.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Suggestion>() {
            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event) {
                // when selection is made we need to combine previously entered text with selected one
                box.setText(startingText + box.getText() + endingText);
                // set cursor position at the end of selected text
                box.setCursorPos(startingText.length() + event.getSelectedItem().getReplacementString().length());
            }
        });

        initWidget(suggestBox);
    }
}
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]